# Summing row elements of two time series objects in R

Tags: r

I have a two `ts` object as follows

```
> ts_forecast$mean
     Sep      Oct      Nov
5 12.74330 13.44875 14.15419
```

And

```
> tail(ts_full$time.series[,2],n=3)
   Jun      Jul      Aug
5 55.22149 55.64993 56.22575
```

`ts_forecast$mean` I have got from a `stlf` forecast function `(package forecast)`. 
`ts_full` is nothing but the Random part of the time series and was obtained as

```
ts_full <-stl(ts_historic,s.window='periodic') 
ts_full$time.series[,2] <----Trend part
ts_full$time.series[,3] <-----Random Part and this was used in stlf forecast function.
```

Objective: I want to add the Trend part to the three forecast values as obtained above.

In simple terms:

```
forecast_mean <-ts_forecast$mean + tail(ts_full$time.series[,2],n=3)
```

But I am getting a Warning Message:

```
 Warning message:
In .cbind.ts(list(e1, e2), c(deparse(substitute(e1))[1L], deparse(substitute(e2))[1L]),  :
non-intersecting series
```

I do not want to use `mean(tail(ts_full$time.series[,2],n=3))` and add the same to `ts_forecast$mean`.
What I am missing here? Is it because of different months for `ts_forecast$mean` and  `ts_full`?

Appreciate any clue.

Comment: Yes, you are correct it because of the different months for ts_forecast$mean and ts_full.

Comment: What is the way out?

Answer (score 0):

```
forecast_mean <- suppressWarnings(as.numeric(ts_forecast$mean) + as.numeric(tail(ts_full$time.series[,2],n=3)))
```

Comment: This would give `interger[0]`

Comment: @pythondumb try the above, convert them to numeric vectors.